# How do I pass a function as a property to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

In an effort to figure out the problem I explain in my (unanswered) question ["How do I update a react-bootstrap-table2 cell value after it's edited so a button component in a different column has it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58584680/4766), I attempted to pass a function that returns the cell value into the button component:

```
class NominationQueueBootstrapTable extends Component {

...

  getInitialBid = (row) => {
    console.log('getInitialBid');
    return this.state.data.find(r => r.rank === row.rank).initialBid;
  }

  render() {
    const { auctionId } = this.props;
    const { teamId } = this.props;

    function buttonFormatter(cell, row) {
      return (
        <NominateButton
          row={ row }
          auctionId={ auctionId }
          teamId={ teamId }
          getInitialBid={ this.getInitialBid }
        />
      );
    }

...
```

My `NominateButton` component returns another button wrapper component that calls a mutator:

```
class NominateButton extends Component {
  render() {
    const { row } = this.props;
    const { auctionId } = this.props;
    const { teamId } = this.props;
    const playerId = parseInt(this.props.row.player.id, 10);

    return (
      <Query
        query={TEAM_NOMINATIONS_OPEN_QUERY}
        variables={{ team_id: teamId }}>
        {({ data, loading, error, subscribeToMore }) => {
          if (loading) return <Loading />;
          if (error) return <Error error={error} />;
          return (
            <NominateButtonMutator
              auctionId={ auctionId }
              teamId={ teamId }
              playerId={ playerId }
              row={ row }
              nominationsOpen={ data.team.nominationsOpen }
              subscribeToNominationsOpenChanges={ subscribeToMore }
              getInitialBid={ this.props.getInitialBid }
            />
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}
```

And because I need to invoke the mutator when the button is pressed, my onClick function first calls the getInitialBid function passed in as a property, and then invokes the mutator:

```
class NominateButtonMutator extends Component {

...

  handleButtonPressed = (submitBid) => {
    this.setState({bidAmount: this.props.getInitialBid(this.props.row)});
    submitBid();
  };

  render() {
    const { auctionId } = this.props;
    const { teamId } = this.props;
    const { playerId } = this.props;
    const { nominationsOpen } = this.props;

    return (
      <Mutation
        mutation={SUBMIT_BID_MUTATION}
        variables={{
          auction_id: auctionId,
          team_id: teamId,
          player_id: playerId,
          bid_amount: this.state.bidAmount
        }}
      >
        {(submitBid, { loading, error }) => (
          <div>
            <Error error={error} />
            <Button
              disabled={ loading || !nominationsOpen }
              onClick={() => this.handleButtonPressed(submitBid) }
              variant="outline-success">
              Nominate
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}
```

*(The `onClick=` code was updated from [azium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225108/azium)'s comment.)*

When I run this, I get:

"TypeError: this.props.getInitialBid is not a function"

[image]

Is this a workable strategy? Why isn't this.props.getInitialBid a function?

Comment: I'm not sure this would fix it, but this looks wrong `onClick={ this.handleButtonPressed(submitBid) }` surely you meant `onClick={() =>  this.handleButtonPressed(submitBid) }`

Comment: You're right! Thank you! But now I get the error when I press the button. I'll update my question.

Comment: So, the code looks right to me. Have you tried putting `console.log(this.props)` in each components render method to make sure you're passing it down correctly?

Comment: I have not. I should have. I will now.

Comment: It's undefined.  

Comment: is it `undefined` in `NominateButton` too? Double check all your spellings!

Comment: oh! I think I've spotted your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old `function` syntax, so `this` is not bound correctly.

change:

```
function buttonFormatter(cell, row) {
  return (
    <NominateButton
      row={ row }
      auctionId={ auctionId }
      teamId={ teamId }
      // scoped to your local function not your class
      getInitialBid={ this.getInitialBid } 
    />
  );
}
```

to

```
const buttonFormatter = (cell, row) => {
  return (
    <NominateButton
      row={ row }
      auctionId={ auctionId }
      teamId={ teamId }
      // this is scoped "lexically" aka to your class
      getInitialBid={ this.getInitialBid }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that should be `const buttonFormatter = (cell, row) => { ...`?

Comment: That was it! `this.props.getInitialBid` is no longer undefined in the button components. Thank you!